# How do I store Google Maps in a Redux store?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, redux

I have a Chrome Extension where I use `redux` actions to pass messages between the `content` script and the `background` script.

Because I can't load the Google Maps `script` tag in a `content` script, I'm trying to keep it loaded in the `background` script & pass it to the `content` script when needed.

In the `background` script, I run the following:

```
  // this asynchronously inserts a script tag & calls a callback upon completion
  import load from 'little-loader' 

  window._dispatchMap_ = () => {
     store.dispatch({type: 'MAPS_LOADED', payload: google.maps})
  }

 load('https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=<redacted>&libraries=places&callback=_dispatchMap_', (err) => {
      if (err) console.error(err)
    })
```

The `redux` action dispatches correctly, and in my `background.html`, `redux logger` shows the correct payload.  When I check the size of the `google.maps` obj in the console:

`> Object.keys(google.maps).length   // 66 keys`

However, when the `payload` gets stored in my `redux` store (in the `background` still), it's only saved with 30 keys. So when it arrives in my `content` script (to a React component, `google-map-react`), it fails to load correctly.

Why can't the `google.maps` object make it into `redux` store fully intact?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this usually means that you need to include your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Thank you, @Makyen, but your comment feels like a hasty and generic criticism of my post.  The `manifest.json` is fully irrelevant here, and I've already included some of the `background.js` script. If there is specific information that I'm missing, please advise and I'll add it, but otherwise: I've included my source code with which I am having the problem, described the actual and expected outcome, and included steps to recreate.

Comment: My comment, which, yes, is a boilerplate, is a reminder that what is required of a debugging question is that sufficient code for us to *duplicate the problem* must be included in the question. Your question doesn't have enough information for us to duplicate the problem. It doesn't even have explicit statements in the text as to what the methods being used do (code showing how they are defined would be better). The *manifest.json* is mentioned because it controls how a Chrome extension is organized. Without it, we have to assume quite a bit of information about your code.

Comment: Without being able to duplicate the problem, all we can really do is either help you with debugging, or make guesses as to the cause of the problem.

Comment: I respect & appreciate your wanting to keep questions up to a certain standard (it's a thankless job I'd wager), but I don't agree with your conclusions. The only methods in my snippet are (a) `dispatch`, which is a core method of `redux`, and (b) `load`, which I annotated with a comment. Ultimately I don't agree that this is a question of debugging. There is no room for programmer error in the code involved in this question, so the question is more appealing to anyone who might know enough about `redux` to opine. It being in an extension may not matter, but if it does, I wanted to mention it.

Comment: Your first line states that you are passing the data from a background script to a content script, which caries its own requirements for the Object being passed. While you later state that the Object is only saved into your redux store with 30 keys, it is not clear to me that you are checking it in the redux store, or after it is transmitted to the content script. It sounds like debugging this might benefit, for testing, from reducing the complexity by trying to do basically the same thing, but from a normal page script, without the complications of having it in a Chrome extension.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point, I'll edit to clarify (the  redux store in the background script held only 30 keys). I hope I don't sound obstinate wrt providing more towards reproduction, it's just that the extension uses a boilerplate with multiple libraries configured to abstract away message passing with redux. I'll try and set up a repo tomorrow, but there's just no way to include all relevant code within the question.

Comment: I do recommend trying to duplicate this in a non-extension environment. Particularly for libraries, the extension environment can introduce strange-isms when the code is assuming that it is running in a "normal" web page environment. Being able to duplicate the problem, or not, in a more "normal" environment would help significantly reduce the possible problem set.